# How can i run the task only once in this task

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this below piece of code inside my WebApplication , which basically does this , whenever  a user logs into the Application .

1. The addSymbols Method will be getting called during  user logon operation .
2. As a result of above , the PriorityBlockingQueue gets fired up
3. The PriorityBlockingQueue adds the symbol to the HashSet ,  which is then iterated to run a particular task on that  newly added symbol.

The issue i am facing here is that , the while loop which is part of HashSet is executing the same task over and over again as it being inside a while true condition of a Thread .

I am pasting the sample output as to understand  the context related to it .

```
Symbol From priorityBlocking  SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
Symbol From allSymbolsSet   SymbolTest
```

This is my code which does the above described .

```
package com;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

public class TaskerThread extends Thread {
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<String> priorityBlocking = new PriorityBlockingQueue<String>();
    private Set<String> allSymbolsSet = new HashSet<String>();
     ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public void addSymbols(String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            priorityBlocking.add(str);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                while (priorityBlocking.peek() != null) {
                    String symbol = priorityBlocking.poll();
                    allSymbolsSet.add(symbol);
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Symbol From priorityBlocking" +"  "+ symbol);
                    }   catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Iterator<String> ite = allSymbolsSet.iterator();
                while (ite.hasNext()) {
                    String symbol = ite.next();
                    if (symbol != null && symbol.trim().length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Symbol From allSymbolsSet"+"   "+symbol);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            TaskerThread qT = new TaskerThread();
            qT.start();
            qT.addSymbols("SymbolTest");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any way i can make the Iterator task run only once .

Comment: I cannot keep the iteration part code , outside the while true condition , because if i do so , i will miss the task to be executed if any new user is logged on .

Comment: Not sure if it solves any problems, but you might want to use [`take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) or [`poll(long,TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) since they block. This would prevent the loop from running when there's nothing in the queue. You should also be able to remove the manual `sleep` then.

Comment: you add symbol in allSymbolsSet but you never remove them. So inside your while(true) you'll always print all your symbols

Comment: @fluminis how removing symbols from a allSymbolsSet  will help here ?? as each user has got a unique symbol .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see. Here's what's happening:

Your loop starts, and a symbol gets added to the queue. It gets pulled off the queue in the thread loop, and then the iterator loop runs. Then the outer loop (`while (true)`) goes around again, and this time, there's no symbol to add, but the iterator loop still executes. You need to only execute the iterator loop if a new symbol has been added:

```
            boolean added = false;
            while (priorityBlocking.peek() != null) {
                added = true;
                String symbol = priorityBlocking.poll();
                allSymbolsSet.add(symbol);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Symbol From priorityBlocking" +"  "+ symbol);
                }   catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (added) {
                Iterator<String> ite = allSymbolsSet.iterator();
                while (ite.hasNext()) {
                    String symbol = ite.next();
                    if (symbol != null && symbol.trim().length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Symbol From allSymbolsSet"+"   "+symbol);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Alternatively, using [`take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) or [`poll(long,TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) would also stop your loop while you don't have anything to add. This should also keep the second part of the loop from running unnecessarily. You'll just need to handle the `InterruptedException`.

Comment: i took your code and ran that , but i still see the Iterator continously getting executed . This is expected as once the flag is set to true it runs continously know , please tell me if i missed anything .

Comment: The flag is local to the `try` block. It should get a new value every time the loop goes around. If you only add once, then it should only execute once. If you add multiple items, it would execute each time something is added.

Comment: thanks that makes sense , tried it now , seems good , this is working fine , but could you please tell me what benefit i get if i use take from priorityBlockingQueue instead of the above code which you pasted .

Comment: Currently, the outer `white (true)` loop runs every 2 seconds whether there's anything to do or not. When nothing is added, that entire iteration is essentially a waste of CPU cycles. By using `take`, the thread will be totally inactive until something is added to the queue. It will result in less contention for processor time, so other threads that actually have work to do can do so. Using `take` will probably require a more significant rework in the code, though. Multithreading can be quite the pain at times.